# No sé sumar progresivamente los valores de una matriz en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase de JavaScript y estoy muy bloqueado. Tengo la siguiente matriz:

```
let matriz = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
```

Ahora bien, se me pide que recorra toda la matriz, sume los valores que están en cada posición de la matriz y devuelva un sumatorio. Estoy muy bloqueado porque no soy capaz de almacenar el sumatorio. Mi código:

```
function sumaNumeros() {
    matriz.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
        let sumatorioNumeros = 0 + matriz[i][j];
        console.log(sumatorioNumeros);
    })
}
```

Con el forEach consigo recorrer la matriz sin problema. El problema viene a la hora de almacenar los valores: ejecutándolo así me dice que i y j no están definidas, pero es que si pongo `let sumatorioNumeros+=matriz[i][j]` me da error, porque imagino que += no se podrá hacer en JavaScript. Yo por ahora lo que mejor manejo es Java que ahí sí que se puede hacer perfectamente.

He hecho el pseudocódigo y estos son los pasos que creo que he de hacer:

> 1. Crear función
> 2. Recorrer matriz
> 3. Tengo que ir guardando en una variable la suma de recorrer las distintas posiciones de la matriz
> 4. Finalmente puedo mostrar el valor por console.log o en un alert

Es ahí justo en el paso 3 dónde estoy bloqueado. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falto un par de cosas:

1. Estas declarando(`let sumatorioNumeros = 0 + matriz[i][j]`) de nuevo en cada iteración, por lo cual se borran los resultados anteriores.
2. Las variables `i,j` no esta definidas, y aun que estén es un peligro porque hay veces que no sabemos la longitud del array y si ese índice no existe nos dará error.

Dicho esto lo que te faltaría es un par de cambios y recorrer un nivel mas abajo.

Tu código quedaría así:

```js
let matriz = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

function sumaNumeros() {
  let sumatorioNumeros = 0;
    matriz.forEach(element => {
        //element es un array tambien.
      element.forEach(num => { //Nivel n.2
        sumatorioNumeros += num;
      })

    })
    console.log("El total es: "+ sumatorioNumeros )
}

sumaNumeros()
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 5):

Una forma en la que puede resolverse es usando `.reduce()`, como tiene 2 dimensiones, podemos hacer `.flat()` antes para quitar una de esas dimensiones:

```js
let matriz = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

const res = matriz.flat().reduce((p,c)=>p+c);

console.log(res);
```

Si los números van a ser consecutivos y comienzan con 1, podes usar la fórmula `n*(n+1)/2`, donde `n` es el `length`.

```js
let matriz = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

const n = matriz.flat().length;

const res = n*(n+1)/2;

console.log(res);
```

Comment: +1 Muy buena solución y se ve mucho más limpio

Comment: +1, lastima que `flat` no es soportado por `Edge`

Answer (score 0):

Una solución que podrías aplicar es:

- Convertimos la matriz bidimensional a unidimensional (`Array.prototype.concat.apply([], matriz) --> array`)
- Recorremos el arreglo resultante y sumamos los valores (`array.reduce((a, v) => a + v) --> number`)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let matriz = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

const res = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], matriz).reduce((a, v) => a + v);
console.log(res)
```

#### Referencias:

- [function.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/apply)
- [array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat)
- [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)